# Failed to load resource error https://graph.facebook.com/667771081/picture?type=normal

Tags: php, html, image, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to load profile picture from Facebook Graph but it throws an error.
Please help me to get rid of this error.

Comment: You should not use `mysqli_` functions with `mysql` functions.

Comment: You need to use [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add values like `$pid` to your query or you'll end up with massive [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Can anyone answer this question. I have changed it. Answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `mysqli_fetch_array($qbids)` insted of `mysql_fetch_array($qbids)`

Comment: Kindly read the question and answer me. I have changed the question.

Comment: @ManzorAhmadBajwa no ! you shouldn't change question ! please revert to old, and ask new question